# valgrind to detect memory leak in child process

Tags: valgrind

I am using spawn-fcgi to start my application which take 3 parameters.
when i try to use valgrind it gives no leak information.

i am using this command

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check-full --trace-children=yes spawn-fcgi -s tempSocket ./myApp param1 param2 param3
```

spawn-fcgi only take one parameter and created child process for application.

Is there any way to get memory leakage for application?

Comment: That should do it. Are you sure there's a memory leak?

Comment: @slugonamission I am checking application to find memory leak if any. Below is the result:

==10228== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10228== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10228== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10228== Command: ./myApp param1 param2 param3
==10228== Parent PID: 10221
==10228==
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@==10221== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close()
I am unable to put complete result due to character limitation in comment.

Comment: @Anurag edit your original post with valgrind's output.

Comment: Thanks @slugonamission. My same command worked. It might i am doing some mistake the day of posting this question.